# TestFlight missing an app

Tags: ios7, testflight

Using TestFlight for testing my iOS apps, there are times when, for an unknown reason one app will not show up on devices. Has anyone experienced this kind of situation?
Is there a solution?
Since I have many other apps on TestFlight, I do not think it is a basic setting issue like a device UDID not included or something similar.

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? It might help other if you were to post any solutions that worked for you.

Comment: No, I actually had forgotten about this question:). You know some problems appears you don't know why, and they disappears you don't know why. I suppose I just had to wait a bit. TestFlight has lost its simplicity and speed since it got in the hands of Apple. It may have improved in some respects, but those I personally do not see.